# WPF RadioButton GroupName scope

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button, groupname

Its clear that by default a `RadioButton`'s `GroupName` is scoped to the parent container. In this case, two `RadioButton`s each placed at different tab of `TabControl` will not be grouped together. Check the following example as an instance

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Grid>
                <RadioButton GroupName="A" Content="RB 1"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Grid>
                <RadioButton GroupName="A" Content="RB 2"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

I was wondering how would it be possible to *extend* the `GroupName` scope so that when `RB 1` is checked, `RB 2` will be un-checked and visa-versa.

I came across interesting solutions such as [this question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3b07622f-2244-48c1-ad14-9769a9e79d35/how-to-split-a-group-of-radio-buttons-across-tabs?forum=wpf) which works by `Binding` the `IsChecked` property of `RadioButton`s to a converter. Although it works perfectly, but I would prefer extending the `GroupName` scope somehow.

Comment: In my case, GroupName attribute shared through the whole application. When I create new instance of UserControl containing RadioButton, the RadioButtons of previous UserControl got unchecked.